# IIS 7 really slow concating C# strings

Tags: c#, string, memory, iis-7

We have a large system that has been implemented with a lot of string concatenation - it's everywhere.

We wrote a quick page that concats strings in a loop.  This runs in 3.3s on our dev boxen (debug off) and on our test VMs.  However on production (IIS7) it runs in 15.7s.

Can anyone suggest what we can look at server side (IIS settings, memory settings etc) to account for this?

FYI - Server has tons of free memory and free CPU cycles - so its not a resource problem.  **Rewriting all the code to use string.Join or StringBuilder is not in the budget.**

Comment: How do you concatenate strings, with + or using StringBuilder class?

Comment: Sergey - essentially sStringMain += sStringSub;

Comment: can you show more feasible code where we can see what it is you're doing opposed to us having to guess or play mind reader..?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just left debug on on your production box by accident?

Comment: @Jack "We wrote a quick page that concats strings in a loop" so do a quick find replace and use `StringBuilder`.  Otherwise you will have to provide code for us.  The odds are though that it is not a code issue.

Comment: Can you allocate more memory to the application instance?

Comment: What CPUs do you have? 5x is relatively small difference if you happen to have machines with significantly different CPUs - something like 3-4 years old dual/quad CPU server vs. single i5/i7 with 3M+ cache may explain difference and both will show plenty of free CPU due to multiple cores.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same test loop in a console application, then running it in the production server? That way you can make sure that it's IIS 7 that's the problem and not something else.

Comment: are you sure you are testing the same version of the framework? Maybe you are running your Application Pool in .NET 2.0 (like DefaultAppPool) while testing locally in .NET 4.0? One of the biggest challenges you will face soon is a scalability problem since the Garbage collector will need to keep up with String Concatenation leaving so many strings around and it having to collect them that will reduce the scalability of your server significantly.

Comment: @Jack did you have any luck with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

That creates lots of tiny string object in memory, which need to be collected later by Garbage Collector. Replace it with

```
  var sMain = new StringBuilder();
  while (something)
  {
    sMain.Append(sStringSub);
    // ...
  }

  // Call sMain.ToString() when you need the whole string
```

Comment: As I said, this option is not in the budget and it does NOT explain the discrepancy - please read the question before posting answer.

Comment: I would pre-allocate the StringBuilder with more memory. By default it holds 16 characters. It will actually hinder performance just as much once it has to re-allocate a new block of memory for larger data.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That is not the way StringBuilder in .NET works.  Similar to a List, StringBuilder can be expanded without having to copy the old contents into a new array.  Otherwise StringBuilder would be rather useless.  I personally try to set the StringBuilder's capacity on creation if I have a general idea how big it should be, but this is a micro performance optimization which will not be detectable.

Comment: @Trisped Incorrect. ILSpy shows that if the capacity (default: `internal const int DefaultCapacity = 16;`) is expended, it will call it's internal method `private void ExpandByABlock(int minBlockCharCount)` which allocates a new `char[]` (.NET 4, `string` in .NET 2) and rebuilds itself.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead either way your statement "It will actually hinder performance just as much once it has to re-allocate a new block of memory for larger data." is incorrect.

Comment: @Trisped I guess that's true. I benchmarked this a while back on a really beefed up desktop and the difference was only slightly noticable (something in the range of 300-400ms for a large dataset).

Answer (score 2):

Cant believe I'm the first to recommend [RedGates Profiling Tools](http://www.red-gate.com/code-profiling).

**That will tell you exactly what is taking so much time on the server vs the dev PC.**

Strings are reference types stored on the managed heap and therefore subject to Garbage Collection. The GC will promote your strings up the generations (0,1,2) the first time the GC detects it cant free the memory. If you look at [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16273) I bet you will see a tonne of strings allocated to generation 2.

> Rewriting all the code to use string.Join or StringBuilder is not in
>   the budget.

It doesn't matter if its inthe budget or not. If an application takes 15 seconds to respond no one will want to use it and you will not make any money. You will have to change something.

Without the Profiler traces its like taking a shot in the dark... my best guess would be the dev PC has a SSD.

Even though strings are immuatable and a large portion of the memory is likely referring to strings that have been concatenated that the GC couldn't collect. I still dont think this is a memory issue, I bet its something to do with I/O but the profiler traces will confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Diff the website settings on your dev box to your production box. There are many things that might cause the different, everything from worker thread count to max memory size. If these thresholds are crossed IIS will recycle the worker.

Also, are you using IIS or Cassini on the dev box?

Check that your app is not running in debug mode.